# How can I unset css files in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I unset css files in Drupal 6 ?

i.e. I want to unset default.css system.css and system-menu.css

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of Drupal CSS stylesheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340426/how-to-get-rid-of-drupal-css-stylesheets)

Comment: The accepted answer in that 'possible duplicate', along with the contained link should provide all the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your template.php file:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  $css = drupal_add_css();
  unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/system.css']);
  unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/defaults.css']);
  unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/system-menus.css']);
  unset($css['all']['module']['modules/node/node.css']);
  unset($css['all']['module']['modules/user/user.css']);
  $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
}
```

See the [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_css/6) function.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stylestripper](http://drupal.org/project/stylestripper) module lets you selectively deactivate stylesheets from Drupal core.

Comment: Crap! I wish I knew that existed or I wish I didn't need it.